# How can I use if/else in list comprehensions?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list with even numbers showing as they are and odd numbers showing as "odd".

Here is the code I am trying.

```
lst = [if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(11)]
```

I expected to get something like this

```
[0, "odd", 2, "odd", 4, "odd", 6, "odd", 8, "odd", 10]
```

But I keep getting `SyntaxError` exception:

```
>>> lst = [if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(11)]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    lst = [if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(11)]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the `x` before `if`:

```
lst = [x if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(11)]
```

The Python [conditional expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) *has* to have both the 'true' and the 'false' expressions present, so `true_expr if condition else false_expr`, where one of `true_expr` or `false_expr` will be evaluated based on the truth value of the `condition` expression.

Demo:

```
>>> [x if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(11)]
[0, 'odd', 2, 'odd', 4, 'odd', 6, 'odd', 8, 'odd', 10]
```

Note that using a conditional expression *doesn't filter*, it always produces output. That's great for the per-iteration expression side of the list comprehenion syntax, but if you wanted to filter the input list and remove odd values altogether, then use a `if condition` test *after* the `for ... in ...` loop:

```
>>> [x for x in range(11) if x % 2 == 0]  # filtering, only even numbers
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

```
[x if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(11)]
[0, 'odd', 2, 'odd', 4, 'odd', 6, 'odd', 8, 'odd', 10]
```

If that is the case you where simply missing something to return in the list comprehension, in this case you want to return `x` if the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

```py
lst = [x if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(11)]
```

for more details regarding list comprehension and ternary operator, here the links:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the value that should be shown if the if statement is true

```
[if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(11)]
```

should be

```
[x if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(11)]
```